# Task.ContinueWith fires before task is finished

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5

I'm trying to start a task after I register a continuation for it. But continuation fires immediately after `await Task.Delay()` is called.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication30
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = new Task(async delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("Before delay");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("After delay");
            });

            task.ContinueWith(t => {
                Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith");
            });

            task.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Before delay
ContinueWith
After delay
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `new Task(` -> `new Task<Task>(`,`task.ContinueWith` -> `task.Unwrap().ContinueWith`

Comment: There is almost no reason to use `new Task (` unless you are writing a task scheduler. Use `Task.Run (` instead

Comment: I'm trying to make a task that removes itself from task list when it finishes. To do it safely I need to ensure that it is added to the list before it is started. I'm trying to do the following: create a task, add it to the list, register continuation that removes it, start the task. Is there a better way?

Comment: That's not the part where you have the problem. The problem is that the continuation is wired to the wrong task, because you don't understand how `async` works. Your task finishes as soon as it reaches the first `await`, because there's no connection between the inner task (the one awaiting `Task.Delay`) and the outer task (that you explicitly created with `new Task`). As Scott said, *don't use the task constructor*. The code will work fine with `Task.Run` (and you shouldn't really use that either - just run the code, no need to post it to another thread just to return immediately).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem - as others have noted - is that `Task.Task` does not understand `async` delegates. As I describe on my blog, [the `Task` constructor should never be used](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html) - it has literally *zero* use cases.

If you want to run code on a thread pool thread, use `Task.Run`.

Also, you [shouldn't use `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html); it's an extremely low-level and dangerous API (as described on my blog). You should use `await` instead.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("Before delay");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("After delay");
        });

        await task;
        Console.WriteLine("await");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a loop that launches tasks and puts them into a List. I wanted tasks to remove themselves from this list upon completion. But current task doesn't have a reference to itself (at least I think it doesn't). That's why I used .ContinueWith to remove them.

Comment: @Poma: You should still use `await`. Using `ContinueWith` and ignoring the returned task is roughly the same as using `await` within an `async` method and ignoring the returned task. (Except `await` has more reasonable default behavior).

Comment: @StephenCleary I have been pulling my hair for a while trying to arrange my case :( `public async Task<TenantDto> CreateAsync(CreateTenantDto input)
 {
 try
 {
  TenantDto newTenantDto = null;
  using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(new AbpUnitOfWorkOptions { IsTransactional = true }))
  {
   --Insert #1 (parent entity)
   uow.OnCompleted(async () =>
   {
    --Insert #2 (child entity)
   });
   await uow.CompleteAsync();
   return newTenantDto; // is null, because OnCompleted is not called yet!
  }
 }
 ...
}`

Comment: @Alexander: Please ask your own question; it's difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: @StephenCleary please have a look! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069170/cannot-insert-two-entities-using-3rd-party-unitofwork-component
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use `Task.Run`

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(async()=>{
                Console.WriteLine("Before delay");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("After delay");
            }).ContinueWith(t => {
                // do somthing with your Task t here
                Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith");
            });

           // task.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
```

**Output:**

> Before delay 
>   After delay  
>   ContinueWith

Why your code doesn't work:
Look at your example (a bit modified):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var outerTask = new Task(async delegate {
        Console.WriteLine("Before delay");
         await Task.Delay(1000); // inner task
        Console.WriteLine("After delay");
    },"Outertask");

    outerTask.ContinueWith(t => {
        Console.WriteLine("ContinueWith");
    });

    outerTask.Start();
    outerTask.Wait(); // wait for outerTask to finish
    var breakHere = 0; // set a brakpoint here
}
```

You get a reference to the outerTask.
The outerTask has no connection to the innerTask.
After calling start, the outerTasks triggers execution of the delegate and continues immediately with "ContinueWith" delegate.
The continuation is connected to the outerTask!

OP's comment:

> I'm trying to make a task that removes itself from task list when it
>   finishes. To do it safely I need to ensure that it is added to the
>   list before it is started. I'm trying to do the following: create a
>   task, add it to the list, register continuation that removes it, start
>   the task. Is there a better way?

While the following code works, you have to justify the usage first!
The code is not optimized or whatever. Ther are or for sure better patterns out there. Do your research.

```
ConcurrentBag<AsyncLazy<Task>> taskList = new ConcurrentBag<AsyncLazy<Task>>();
void Main()
{
    int v = 3242;
    AsyncLazy<Task> objAsyncLazy = null;
    objAsyncLazy = new AsyncLazy<Task>(new Func<Task<Task>>(async () =>
   {
       return await Task.FromResult<Task>(doLongRunningAsync(v).
                    ContinueWith<Task>(async (doLongRunningAsyncCompletedTask) =>
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(doLongRunningAsyncCompletedTask.IsCompleted); // 
                       await removeMeFromListAsync(objAsyncLazy);
                   }));
   }));

    taskList.Add(objAsyncLazy);
    Console.WriteLine("al added");
    Console.WriteLine("ConcurrentBag.Count: " + taskList.Count);
    // execute the task
    var t = objAsyncLazy.GetValueAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

    // wait for the first task "t" to finish or not, 
    // ContinueWith will execute after first task "t" has finished anyways. 
    t.Wait(); 
    // ContinueWith is executing now
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public async Task doLongRunningAsync(int val)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before delay" + val);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("After delay");
}

public async Task removeMeFromListAsync(AsyncLazy<Task> al) //(AsyncLazy<Task> t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("continue start");
    taskList.TryTake(out al);
    Console.WriteLine("al removed");
    Console.WriteLine("ConcurrentBag.Count: " + taskList.Count);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("continue end");
}
}
```